# Mathematical Pendulum DGL

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been given the problem regarding a mathematical pendulum:
$$\ddot{\phi}=-g\cdot sin\phi -c\cdot \dot {\phi} $$ 
where $-c\cdot \dot {\phi} $ is the friction within the joint and l=1m, m=1kg.
I've been asked to convert it into a system of first order differential equations by adding a variable and then examine the points of stability.

I'm pretty sure that the stability part i can do, but I'm having trouble finding a place to start with the conversion to a system. We've delt with $$\ddot{\phi}=\frac {-g}{l}\cdot sin\phi $$ in class, which we solved by setting 
$$\phi ' = \frac {1}{l}v $$
$$v(t)=l\cdot  \phi '(t) $$
$$v'(t)=-g\cdot sin \phi $$
and I understand the similarities but the difference is really throwing me off.

How do I approach this problem in order to solve it?

Edit: think I may have copied something wrong in class (or not understood). This form is clearer to me:
\begin{align}
\dot{\phi}&=\frac{1}{l}v \\
\dot{v}&=-g\cdot sin\phi \\
\ddot{\phi}&=\frac{1}{l}\dot{v} \\
&=-\frac{g}{l}sin\phi\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have
\begin{align}
\ddot \phi = -g\sin\phi -c \dot\phi 
\end{align}
then by setting $v = \dot \phi$ we get the system 
\begin{align}
\dot \phi=&\ v\\
\dot v =&\ -g \sin \phi -cv.
\end{align}
or in matrix form
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot \phi\\
\dot v
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & -c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi\\
v
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-g\sin \phi
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: Ahhh! OK. I think I understand now. Think I also think I may have copied something wrong. I'll update my question as well